# Unable to test two rake tasks in one file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake

I'm trying to write some basic smoke tests for a few rake tasks. For reasons that I don't understand, I get a `Don't know how to build task...` error if both are uncommented. If I commend out *either* one it works fine (in any order).

spec/tasks/foo_spec.rb

```
require "rails_helper"
require "rake"

describe "Foo rake tasks" do
  before do
    @rake = Rake::Application.new
    Rake.application = @rake
    Rake.application.rake_require "../rakelib/foo"
    Rake::Task.define_task(:environment)
  end

  describe "rake foo:bar" do
    before do
      @task_name = "foo:bar"
    end

    it "runs without errors" do
        expect { @rake[@task_name].invoke('1') }.not_to raise_error
    end
  end

  describe "rake foo:rab" do
    before do
      @task_name = "foo:rab"
    end

    it "runs without errors" do
        expect { @rake[@task_name].invoke('1', 'boo') }.not_to raise_error
      end
    end
  end

end
```

This setup is an adaption from [this tutorial](http://www.philsergi.com/2009/02/testing-rake-tasks-with-rspec.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works, adapted from [this](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/test-your-rake-tasks).

```
require "rails_helper"
require "rake"

describe "Foo rake tasks" do

  before :all do
    Rake.application.rake_require "../rakelib/foo"
    Rake::Task.define_task(:environment)
  end

  describe "rake foo:bar" do
    let :run_rake_task do
      Rake::Task["foo:bar"].reenable
      Rake.application.invoke_task "foo:bar"
    end

    it "runs without errors" do
      expect { run_rake_task }.not_to raise_error
    end
  end
end
```